# Create custom menu in php based on pagenames

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

im trying to make a custom hardcoded menu in a wordpress page-template. The site has 3 pages (1, 2, 3) and at page 1 i wish to loop trough all pages that has page1 as pagetemplate and 2 for 2 etc.

How can i loop trough and get the names of all pages so i can put them in a menu?

if for example you visit page 1 and the pages that has page1 as template (parent) are "visit us" and "read more" the menu would look like this:

-visit us
-read more

but if i go to page 2 the menu might look like this:

-funpark
-foobar

Now if I add a new page with "1" as parent and name the page "about" the new menu will now show

-visit us
-read more
-about

Cheers,
Emil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query for pages and their template value. The codex says:

> The filename of a Page's assigned custom template is stored as the value of a Custom Field named '_wp_page_template' (in the wp_postmeta database table). (Custom fields starting with an underscore do not display in the Edit screen's Custom Fields module.)

This means you can build a page query like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page', 
    'meta_query' => array( 
        array(
            'key'   => '_wp_page_template', 
            'value' => '[Your template goes here]'
         )
    )
);
```

All you have to do is loop through the pages, get the permalink and build your menu.

Comment: awesome! So simple and elegant :D!